# Decode ASCII to Text in C#

Tags: c#

Hi I am trying to decode the following string 10410532119111114108100 I just encoded in ascii, now I want to convert a string to plain text as well, I have the following code:

```
    int texto = 10410532119111114108100;
    string resultado = "";

    resultado = resultado + System.Convert.ToChar(texto);

    Console.WriteLine(resultado);
```

but does not work, someone can help me?

Comment: What is `texto`? You said it's string, but the type in code is int.

Comment: You haven't told us anything about what the numbers mean or how they're grouped. How many digits represent a character?

Comment: There is no chance you have an integer that long http://ideone.com/4xMQr3 "I just encoded in ascii" --- how did you do that?

Comment: you say "the following string 10410532119111114108100" but your code says `int texto = 10410532119111114108100;` -- something is off here.

Comment: There is a problem of trying to figure out exactly what it could be.  The first ASCII character could be 1, 10 or 104.  If you use octal, then it would be easy to go back in forth, since they're three digits each per specification (`000`, `001`, etc.).  You would know for sure that it's every three digits.

Answer (score 5):

```
var asciiBytes = new byte[] { 104, 105, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100 };
var text = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(asciiBytes);
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

This prints

```
hi world
```

Leaving aside issues with language syntax, there is a fundamental problem in your code. Each character corresponds to an ASCII code from 0 to 255. E.g. "hi world" corresponds to 104, 105, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100. If you erase spaces between individual codes and create one long string of digits, there may be more than one way to break it back into individual codes. E.g. 10410532119111114108100 can arise from you original sequence, but also from {104,10,53,21, 19...} or {10,4,105,32,11,91...), etc. Therefore, there is no way to convert long string of digits without spaces back to characters.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are mixing a `char` with a `char[]`  ...

First of all, your text (`texto`) is an `int`, but it's too big for one to begin with.

Second of all, `System.Convert.ToChar()` expects to convert something into a Unicode char (only 1), so passing it an int which is not valid (sizewise) to begin with, is completely wrong.

Have a look at [ToChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tochar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to see how it's used.

Assuming you are just converted a string into char values, i tried breaking up your string to something like :

```
var list = new List<int>{104,105,321,191,111,141,081,00};

foreach (var element in list)
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine(Convert.ToChar(element));
}
// will output ->  hiŁ¿oQ□ . Doubt it's what you've encoded though
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fallow a simple pattern here. i have encountered with the same problem

This is the ascii table : http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif

And my pattern is not fully covers every possibility but it is a solution for simple texts.

Here is the code :

```
string input = "10410532119111114108100";
string playground = input;
string result = "";
while (playground.Length > 0)
{
  int temp = Convert.ToInt32(playground.Substring(0, 2));
  if (temp < 32)
  {
     temp = Convert.ToInt32(playground.Substring(0, 3));
  }
  result += (Convert.ToChar(temp)).ToString();
  playground = playground.Substring(temp.ToString().Length, playground.Length - temp.ToString().Length);
}
```